# TimeZone on nodeJs using oAuth

Tags: node.js, oauth, express, tumblr

I am working with the tumbler API and I am using the express framework for node.js, but I have a problem using the tumblr oAuth. The problem is the difference in timezones.

How I can change my current timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the TZ environment variable before calling any date functions.

```
> process.env.TZ = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
'Europe/Amsterdam'
> d = new Date()
Wed Mar 06 2013 23:30:42 GMT+0100 (CET)
> d.toString()
'Wed Mar 06 2013 23:30:42 GMT+0100 (CET)'
> d.toUTCString()
'Wed, 06 Mar 2013 22:30:42 GMT'
```

Comment: thank you , but i dont called any Date Object. i just make request from oAuth of NodeJs i need to change the current timezone of the object oAuth()

Comment: OAuth may be using Date internally. Try setting the TZ variable before using OAuth.

Comment: I already test it but it doesn't work :( i think the process.env.TZ it dosent change any thing on runtime :s